# how to configure azure devops sprints to days instead of hours

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

How do you setup Azure Sprints > Board view to show New work and Active work in "Days" instead of hours?

IE: these UI elements here to show a "d" instead of an "h"

[screenshot of what I'm describing - in red what I need changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgqBX.png)

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to do this in TFS but I'm afraid this change cant be done in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is easy and the system is agnostic on the units if you look under the hood. While the sprint capacity and burndown are calculated per day, the number of "units" you use per person per day can be changed.

The default is 8, which is obviously a standard number of work hours. You can simply change this to 1 and now the capacity per person is 1 day. It is just important the unit type (day or hour) that you use in practice between the person capacity and the various work amount fields (size, effort, remaining work, original work, etc.) is the same.

Here are the basic steps to switch to use days:

**Create your own process template** (unless you have one already)

You will often want to change some of the titles of sections or work items, as they often refer to "hours" by default. To do this you need to have your own Process Template. See the following reference to get started on customizing the templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=azure-devops-2020

**Set the Default Capacity for Each Person**

From the Sprints in DevOps, you can specify the capacity per person in the Capacity tab. You can also break down the amount of time per person by the type of activity if you desire. In the end, the numbers should add to 1 per person per day.

Here is a good reference on setting capacities for sprints:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops